# google maps event.addListener with xml

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a dealerlocator with google maps. The problem is that when I click on a icon the infowindow opens the wrong window. I use a xml import. Everything is going well until the infowindow.

see website https://www.turbho.com/dealerview.php

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2maN7CjzWtwI6yuHj8lX078NzV0Ywkg0&sensor=false"></script>

{literal}
<script>
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'

        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        // Try HTML5 geolocation
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                    position.coords.longitude);

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    map: map,
                    position: pos,
                    panControl: true,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    scaleControl: true,
                    content: 'U bent nu hier.'
                });

                map.setCenter(pos);
            }, function () {
                handleNoGeolocation(true);
            });
        } else {
            // Browser doesnt support Geolocation
            handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }

        var image = 'https://turbho.com/img/logoturbhogooglesmall.png';
        // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
        downloadUrl("xml/datacomplete.xml", function (data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                var zipcode = markers[i].getAttribute("zipcode");
                var town = markers[i].getAttribute("town");
                var anchor = markers[i].getAttribute("anchor");
                var website = markers[i].getAttribute("website");
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                var html = "<span style='font-size:12px;'><b>" +
                    name + "</b> <br />" +
                    address + "<br />" +
                    zipcode + " " + town + "<br /><br />" +
                    website + "<br /><br />" +
                    anchor + "</span>";


                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: point,
                    icon: image
                });

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: html
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);

                });
            }
        });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
        if (errorFlag) {
            var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
        } else {
            var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
        }

        var options = {
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
            content: content
        };

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
        map.setCenter(options.position);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
{/literal}

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I used a function see below and that worked for me.

```
function add_marker(latlng, title, box_html, image) {
    //create the global instance of infoWindow 
    if (!window.infowindow) {
        window.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    }

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: title,
        icon: image
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.close();
        infowindow.setContent(box_html);
        infowindow.open(map, this)
    });
    return marker;
}
```

Thanx for the help
Ruud